# Jquery change css property after appending an image

Tags: jquery

im working with jquery. I appended an image into my div-element. it works great.
i want to change a css property (like max-heigth or width etc.) with a js-function.

but nothing works... i tried it with an image fix on the page (withouth appending before, strict in the html..) and that works...

does anybody has an idea??

my function looks like this:

```
function makeBigger() {

 var origHeight = $("#articlePicture").css("max-height");
 var newHeight = parseInt(origHeight.replace("px", ""));

 newHeight+=25;
 newHeight+="px";

 $("#articlePicture").css("max-height", newHeight);
}
```

thanks!

edit: **important to say: it doesn't work only with the appendet picture, firebug etc. everything tried - works!**

edit2: appending-function (kind of an easy version of it..):

```
function appendThis(artikelNumber, pictureToAppend) {
        img="<img src='"+pictureToAppend+"' alt='articlePicture' id='articlePicture' class='articlePicture' />";
        $('.article'+artikelNumber+'Text').append(img);
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you just statically set a value, e.g. $("#articlePicture").css("max-height", "100px");

Comment: no it doesn't even work with something like $("#articlePicture").css("display", "none");
i thinks its somehow a problem of the appending...

Comment: have you looked at the height and width of the div?  Is it keeping you from growing past its size, or maybe a parent of the div?

Comment: no it works... i tried it now with firebug...

Comment: What is the value of the newHeight variable inside that function? Use alert to find out.

Comment: Again: It works for a normal img wich is not appended by my javascript functions. it works. only when i try to append it with a javascript function, it doesnt work anymore... i don't know why?!

Comment: @emre Answer my question please

Comment: @emre Also, how are you appending that image? Post the code.

Comment: @Sime: Why should it be important whats the value is, i tried the same function for an image wich isn't appendet with jquery (.append()-function) and the sizing worked!

The appending code is written above..

Comment: @emre I think the source of the problem is that you set the ID attribute to the same value for each image. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things in your `appendThis` function that could be the reason for it not working.

1. Every time you run this function (and append a new image), you assign the same ID to that image. That is not good, ID's have to be unique on the page. If you have multiple elements with the same ID, jQuery won't be able to select them. You should use the class attribute instead. That way, you can select the images like so: `$('img.articlePicture')`
2. You didn't declare the variable `img`, thus making it an implicit global. This should be avoided, since it can lead to unexpected name-collisions.

I fixed both issues below:

```
function appendThis(n, url) {
    var img = '<img src="' + url + '" class="articlePicture" alt="Picture">';
    $('.article' + n + 'Text').append(img);
}
```

---

Also, here is an optimized version of your makeBigger function:

```
function makeBigger() {   
    $("img.articlePicture").css('max-height', function(i,v) {
        return parseInt(v, 10) + 25 + 'px';
    });
}
```

Comment: hi sime, i'll try it. the first problem is known, but on this page itn't possible anyway to append more than 1 picture. therefore no id problem, so far!
i didn't understand your second reason.. but i'll try?! thanks

Comment: edit:
your second reason: i think i did it, but i had to clear up the whole function, so i forgot the declaration of the variable img. but it's inside my function.. im sure!

Comment: @emre I could solve your problem if I was able to work on the live demo. Would that be possible?

Comment: Hi Sime, okay i'll write tonight again. i hope that you can help me :-)

Comment: Hi Sime!
You were right in a way... It was a really stupid mistake of me...
The problem was: I have more than one div's wich have class="$('.article' + n + 'Text') (exactle 2 divs, one is display:none) and after the appendThis function i've got 2 pictures... WITH THE SAME ID...
--> therefore your answer is right =) 
thanks for your help!! very stupid =(

Comment: @emre Yea, when appending we usually want to make sure that we are appending only to one element. `$('.class').append(stuff)` should only be used if you really want to append to every .class element. Otherwise, you filter the selection, for instance: `$('.class:first').append(stuff)`

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to be bigger just change the height or set the min-height. max-height will not make it bigger it just won't allow it to grow beyond that height.

Comment: I know what min / max height etc means... The picture is definetly bigger... Anyway without appending it works.., why shouldn't it work with append?! thats the main problem!